# Shell echo ${"${FRUIT}_COLOR"} doesn't work as expected

Tags: shell

FRUIT could be "APPLE" or "BANANA"

And fruit's colors are defined as follows:

```
APPLE_COLOR=red
BANANA_COLOR=yellow
```

In a shell, I want to print "red" or "yellow" based on the value of FRUIT.
How can I do that?

```
echo ${"${FRUIT}_COLOR"}
```

This gives me *-bash: ${"${FRUIT}_COLOR"}: bad substitution*

Comment: What you're looking for is called "indirect expansion". See [BashFAQ #6](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006). That said, I'm a little unclear on why a failure would be anything other than expected; do you have a pointer to documentation that implies that the original approach _should_ work?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Oh thanks, I should find another way